# How to insert image in app with appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator

I'm building a simple app with appcelerator.
I would like to set a background image on a view.

This is the code of tss

**login.tss**

```
".images":{
    top: "15px",
    left: "161px",
    backgroundImage : "/images/logo_decipher.PNG",
    width : "268px",
    height : "213px"
}
```

this is a **login.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
        <View class="images"></View>
        <Label id="loginLable"
            class="loginLable">Accedi</Label>
        <TextField class="textLogin"></TextField>
        <Button></Button>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

this is the folder where is my image:

[image]

If I try to start my application the image are not show

Answer (score 0):

All images in Titanium need to be in the `app/assets` folder.

Within the `app/assets` folder you create an `images` folder, and in there you can add your images. Your path you already set will work in that case.

Be aware all images are case sensitive. In case your file is actually `.PNG` then leave it like that.